# PATH environment variable could not be located when trying to install SteamCMD

Tags: path

I am trying to install SteamCMD on my Linux machine by using this [guide](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD).
However, I ran into a problem after I created the user `steam` and installed SteamCMD. The whole error code is

```
Command 'steamcmd' is available in '/usr/games/steamcmd'
The command could not be located because '/usr/games' is not included in the PATH environment 
variable
```

However, I am not that tech savvy with Linux. I am unsure how I am able to give the user `steam` access to that path, so it can execute the steamcmd application.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

`$PATH` is a shell variable that holds the list of directories in which your shell (for example, `bash`) will search for executables. So if you try to run a command named `foo`, your shell will look for an executable file named `foo` in one of those directories. You can see the current value by opening a terminal and running:

```
echo "$PATH"
```

Here, the guide you followed installs the executable `steamcmd` in the directory `/usr/games/` and that directory isn't in your user's `$PATH` variable. So you can either:

1. Call the executable using the full path to it, instead of just the name:

   ```
    /usr/games/steamcmd
   ```
2. Add this directory to your `$PATH`. To do this, edit the file `$HOME/.profile` or, if it exists, the file `$HOME/.bash_profile`. If neither of the two files exist, just create a new, empty `$HOME/.profile` file. In that file, you add this line:

   ```
    export PATH="$PATH:/usr/games"
   ```

   Then, save the file, log out and log back in again and now you can run `steamcmd` as you want.